# Variable not working properly with Reactive Form & Async Service Calls in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-reactive-forms

**Page Design:**

- I have a UI Page which is used to Create/Edit User Role Details in my
  Angular Application.
- The page takes a "role_key" as input from URL
  route params. I subscribe to that route params and get that role_key.
- If role_key exists in route params then i make another api call to
  get details about to that role. The same data is then bind to the
  reactive form. Else an empty form is rendered.
- Based on the role_key, i display either create/update & delete
  buttons below the form.
- Create button is displayed when there is no role_key in url
  params. Update & Delete buttons are displayed when there is a role_key in url
  params.

**Issue:**

The issue is that, even when a role_key exist in route params & a successful api call is made to get the role details about the role_key, the reactive form is still empty and the action buttons, edit & delete are not displayed.
Similary if role_key doesn't exist in the route params, an empty form is rendered but the Create button is not rendered.

Here is my codeblock:

**edit-role.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 d-block">
          <div class="card border-0 card-body shadow-none">
            <!-- <h5>Roles Detail</h5> -->
            <form [formGroup]="roleForm" class="form-horizontal" id="roleForm" name="roleForm"
              data-toggle="validator" role="form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="group_name" class="field-label">Key<span style="color: red"> *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-field" id="role_key" name="role_key"
                      formControlName="role_key" placeholder="Enter role key" [readonly]="role_key" />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="group_id" class="field-label">Name<span style="color: red"> *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-field" id="role_name" name="role_name"
                      formControlName="role_name" placeholder="Enter role name" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="group_description" class="field-label">Description<span style="color: red">
                        *</span></label>
                    <textarea class="form-control text-field" id="role_description" name="role_description"
                      formControlName="role_description" placeholder="Enter role description">
                    </textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row mg-t-40" style="width: 100% !important;">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left" style="text-align: center !important;">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn_update mr-3" (click)="goToList()">
                    Back
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn_update mr-3" *ngIf="role_key == ''"
                    [disabled]="!roleForm.valid" (click)="
                      submitRoleDetails(roleForm.value, roleForm.valid)
                    ">
                    Create
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn_update mr-3" *ngIf="role_key != ''"
                    [disabled]="!roleForm.valid" (click)="
                      submitRoleDetails(roleForm.value, roleForm.valid)
                    ">
                    Update
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn_update mr-3" *ngIf="role_key != ''"
                    (click)="deleteRole(role_key)">
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS File - edit-role.component.ts**

```
// variables
  roleForm: FormGroup;
  loader: boolean = false;
  roleDetails: any;
  role_key: string = '';

  edit: boolean = false


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private toaster: ToasterService, private userService: UsersService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    try {
      this.createNewRoleForm();
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(res => {
        if (res && res.role_key) {
          this.role_key = res.role_key
          this.getRoleDetails();
          this.edit = true;
        }
        else {
          this.role_key = '';
          this.edit = false;
        }
      });
    }
    catch (Ex) {

    }
    finally {
    }

  }

  // create new role form
  createNewRoleForm() {
    this.roleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      role_key: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      role_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      role_description: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
    this.edit = false;
  }

  // get role details
  getRoleDetails() {
    try {
      this.loader = true;
      this.userService.getRoleDetails(this.role_key).subscribe((data) => {
        if (data && data.data) {
          this.roleDetails = data.data;
          this.roleForm.controls.role_key.setValue(this.roleDetails.role_key);
          this.roleForm.controls.role_name.setValue(this.roleDetails.role_name);
          this.roleForm.controls.role_description.setValue(this.roleDetails.role_description);
        }
      }, (error) => {
        this.loader = false;
        this.toaster.error('No Role Found', 'Error');
      });
    }
    catch (ex) { }
    finally {
      this.loader = false;
    }
  }

  
  // delete role
  deleteRole(role_key: string) {
    //delete
  }

  // create / edit role details
  submitRoleDetails(value: any, valid: boolean) {
    if (valid) {
      let payload: any = {};
      payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
      if (this.role_key) {
        this.updateRole(payload);
      } else {
        this.createRole(payload);
      }
    }
  }

  // create role
  createRole(payload) {
     //create
  }

  // update role
  updateRole(payload) {
    //update
  }
```

The edit page is invoked as follows:
**usermanagement/edit-role?role_key=consultant**

Sad Part is this issue is not occuring when i run this code locally, but once it is deployed to a dev or test environment, this issue occurs. So, it is hard for me to reproduce it locally. I have attached the screenshot of the same.

[image: Page that works properly in local]

*Page working properly in local*

[image: Page that has issue after deployed to test/dev]

*Page not working after deployed to test/dev*

So, please help me let me know where and why this code breaks? Is it due to any wrong Async handling or any other issue let me know.

Comment: Try use `if (res && res['role_key'])` or using safe operator `if (res && res?.role_key)` and check the response when you call to `getRoleDetails` using a `console.log(data)`

Comment: Yes, it could be a problem from the network call, you could start with your `ngOnInit` that's where you subscribe to queryparam and call the service.

Comment: @Eliseo, even if the if condition fails due this safe traversal issue, the else part has to work right? But here it seems the variable does not have any value  or doesnt even exist?

Comment: @Jimmy there seems to be no delay in the network call, it is done as the page loads and could see a 200 response with no delay in time.

Comment: follow the flow of your app, first, you have a `ngIf`, so what thing affects this condition? your ngOnInit right? you set the condition there, so start with that function, tracing by console.log or debugger in devtool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. The issue occurred due to a confusion in the app-routing.module.ts code.

1. In lazy loading, for the 'usermanagement/' route i have configured the module 'user-mgmt' as children inside loadChildren ().
2. But in the route-component mapping inside Routes [], i have used mentioned the 'edit-role' component inside the 'users' module (which is unused).
3. Both the user-mgmt and users modules had this same 'edit-role' component with the same code.

This seems to have caused the confusion when the code was deployed and run in the test environment.